# Filter array using multiple keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to render grid with multiple toggling filters. I'm Using react hooks.

This is data array:

```
const items = [
    {
        name: 'hotel1',
        type: 'hotel'
    },
    {
        name: 'bar1',
        type: 'bar'
    },{
        name: 'entertainment1',
         type: 'entertainment'
    },{
        name: 'equipment1',
        type: 'equipment'
    },
    {
        name: 'shop1',
        type: 'shop'
    }
]


    const initialFilters = [
        {
            id: 1,
            active: false,
            type: 'bar'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            active: false,
            type: 'shop'
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            active: false,
            type: 'hotel'
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            active: false,
            type: 'entertainment'
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            active: false,
            type: 'equipment'
        },
    ];

const [data, setData] = useState(items);
const [filterItems, setFilteredItems] = useState(initialFilters);
```

currently I'm filtering with single key that is passed

```
const mainFilter = (key) => {
 setData(items.filter(x => x.type === key));
}
```

and filter buttons with grid item names are rendered:

```
return (
    <div>
        <ul>
            {filterItems.map(x =>
                <li key={x.type}><a
                    className={x.active == true ? 'active' : ''}
                    onClick={() => mainFilter(x.type)}>
                    {x.type}
                </a></li>
            )}
        </ul>
     <div>{data.map(item => <div>{item.name}</div>}</div>
    </div>
)
```

I need to get the functionality where when pressed for example shop filter, it should only leave items with type shop. if you press bar filter, it should only leave items with bar an shop and it should work all the way to all 5 filters. 
if none are selected, it should show full array.

I've tried converting logic from this:

https://gist.github.com/jherax/f11d669ba286f21b7a2dcff69621eb72#file-filterplainarray-js

but no luck yet

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `every` for checking if all flags have value `false`

*This code snippet, have an `initialFilter` with all the flags equal to `false`*

```js
const items = [{name: 'hotel1',type: 'hotel'},{name: 'bar1',type: 'bar'}, {name: 'entertainment1',type: 'entertainment'}, {name: 'equipment1',type: 'equipment'},{name: 'shop1',type: 'shop'}];
const initialFilters = [{id: 1,active: false,type: 'bar'},{id: 2,active: false,type: 'shop'},{id: 3,active: false,type: 'hotel'},{id: 4,active: false,type: 'entertainment'},{id: 5,active: false,type: 'equipment'}];

let allFalse = initialFilters.every(({active}) => !active);
if (allFalse) console.log(items);
```

Otherwise, you can use the function `filter` along with the function `some`:

*This code snippet has as active `shop` and `entertainment`*

```js
const items = [{name: 'hotel1',type: 'hotel'},{name: 'bar1',type: 'bar'}, {name: 'entertainment1',type: 'entertainment'}, {name: 'equipment1',type: 'equipment'},{name: 'shop1',type: 'shop'}];
const initialFilters = [{id: 1,active: false,type: 'bar'},{id: 2,active: true,type: 'shop'},{id: 3,active: false,type: 'hotel'},{id: 4,active: true,type: 'entertainment'},{id: 5,active: false,type: 'equipment'}];

let fltered = items.filter(({type}) => initialFilters.some(({type: t, active}) => t === type && active));
console.log(fltered);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the selected keys and then sort by checking if they are included:

```js
const mainFilter = (keys) => {
 setData(items.filter(x => keys.includes(x.type)));
}
```

This implementation would need a change in your `onClick` function - instead of calling a function with the key you'll need to store the keys.

Comment: I've tried storing keys in array, declaring new array and adding this code in that function:
     const mainFilter = (key) => {

        if(filterArray.includes(key)){
            setFilterArray(filterArray.filter(x => x !== key))
        } else {
            setFilterArray([...filterArray, key]);
        }
    }

        last step would be to get a function which will filter array by array of keys